# My peer-reviewed edits are sometimes re-edited / overwritten, why?

Tags: discussion, edits, review-abuse

My reputation is only enough to edit with a peer-review needed.
I try to edit question & answers to provide help if necessary.

Maybe I'm wrong but I can't seem to see any edits I've made seen as "*edited by me*", but someone else all the time with little to no difference by my edit.

Is it the right way and the way which it should go or is it something done by higher reputation users to get more reputation using their privileges to have the peer-review rights (which is not nice IMHO).

While trying to tag this question, I've found a tag called [review-abuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/review-abuse) so similar question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find prior asking, if this is the case, please provide the link.

For example, just a few minutes ago, a question I edited to give syntax highlighting and added tag [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565665/how-to-refresh-updated-opened-work-item-from-tfs-2013-server-side-plugin).

Comment: Yes, You edited those questions. What happens is that someone else edited them after you, if you click on the "edited" link below the question, you will see the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30565665/revisions), which includes your edit. Those reviewing your edits specifically have an option to "Improve Edit", which means that they can further edit the post, thus adding to or improving your edit. Now, If you fix _all_ problems with the edit, reviewers will not do that. And no, we don't get _anything_ at all for improving / reviewing your edits.

Comment: @JonasCz did you looked into the example I've provided? There is an empty line removal only (: and since this is a new edit, it will be granted +2 rep afaik.

Comment: Yes, I did. The editor who removed the empty line has 2k rep, so they will not be rewarded with 2 rep when editing.  Someone thought that removing that empty line was worth their time, and they did it. So no, the one who removed that empty line did not get 2 rep for doing it.

Comment: @JonasCz (: "removing that empty line was worth their time" was the reason behind my suspicion but thank you for the clear explanation. And glad there is no way that this is a devious way to abuse.

Comment: And for completeness the extra space before the final `}` should have been deleted in that post, as well as the spurious top line (`-------`)

Comment: @BeytanKurt I'm not sure if I offended you, if so that was not my intention. I wanted to show that there are often additional things that can be done that one overlooks and even the reviewer misses. We all do have different focus and things that catch the eye.  I would not be surprised if someone else looked at the post and made more changes (and that doesn't mean they are as pedantic as I am). On reread, maybe you were not referring to my edits in the post you linked to.

Comment: @Anthon, I'm sorry, I took it wrong then. I can surely understand the focus factor. I've been a member for a long time and lately I feel like I need to give as much as I can to SO since I've taken too much from it and this question was a bug for me lately (though I didn't know that >2k users don't gain rep with doing so). I apologize for my quick temper and misunderstanding.

Comment: On the topic of your self-improvement: [this edit of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8274478) got rejected because it is way, way too minor. Yes, it is an improvement; but various *other* issues remained. The Accept/Reject edit routine is (partially) to teach proper editing. (Just picked a random one, no worries - it's part of SO's Learning Experience.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since a reviewer doesn't gain anything except getting a suggested edit review to their name (which doesn't give rep, just a total number of reviews in the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/stats)), it is unlikely that they will do so on purpose, unless they want to prevent other reviewers from  being able to gain a +1 on this statistic (and since there are enough suggested edits if you want to get the max of +20 per day, that is unlikely). So the actual further improvement should be considered nice IMO.

Just to be clear, once you have 2K you cannot propose suggested edits anymore and you cannot gain +2 rep for an accepted edit beyond 2K (except for any non-reviewed items in the queue)¹. As @JonasCz commented this does not apply to tag (wiki/excpert) edits, which require review, of 5K+ users, until you have 20K rep (and earn you +2 if accepted).

That things are always re-edit might just be your impression, and it is always good to see what you might have missed, by looking at the edit revision history of a post you edited, but were not the latest editor for.

As a suggested edit reviewer one has to decide between, accepting; accepting with modifications; declining and editing; declining outright. With the second option selected (and edits saved) the reviewer will both accept your edits and some extra, they might be minor, but the reviewer decides what effort to put in (and once you are looking at the post anyway...).

Actually I often hope that the original, low rep, editor looks at the review history, and learn from it. And sometimes, when glaring changes have been missed in the suggested edit, I will leave a comment asking them to do so and go the extra few inches to make the suggested edit more complete.

In the post you linked two, I [found two more things](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30565665/revisions) I would have changed while reviewing your edit.

---

¹ <sub>A few months ago I reviewed a suggested edit by a user who already had far over 17K rep. The suggested edit had got stuck in the database somehow. I accepted the edit and the suggested editor still got his +2</sub>

Comment: There are of course also a few edit related badges to be gained by making edits, but for those doing the edits on the edist,  the max 20 reviews would be a severely limiting factor, and they gain edits much faster by looking at new questions.